# Linux MS SQL Server evaluation expired, can't upgrade to developer

Tags: sql-server, linux, evaluation

When I installed MS SQL Server for Linux half a year ago, there was no way to choose between evaluation and developer. Now the evaluation period has expired and I can't install a developer version. I don't care about any of my databases and I have tried to remove SQL Server before installing it again. The installation is fine but when I run mssql-conf setup I get the following:

```
Configuring SQL Server...

Error: The evaluation period has expired.
This program has encountered a fatal error and cannot continue running.
The following diagnostic information is available:

       Reason: 0x00000001
       Signal: SIGSEGV - Segmentation fault (11)
   Stacktrace: 0000564434051ee7 00007f9892387b20 00005644340236c2 
               000056443404a8db 000056443404a059 
      Process: 7228 - sqlservr
       Thread: 7253 (application thread 0x1060)
  Instance Id: 357ebf86-214d-4100-b14f-cb62b380917e
     Crash Id: 
  Build stamp: 3db4cdd88f9bbf816f82e0ab6e17825a0a0f8b2ef98a5c67b521be0ed19c297c
/opt/mssql/lib/mssql-conf/invokesqlservr.sh: line 15:  7227 Aborted                 sudo -EH -u mssql /bin/bash -c "$CMDLINE"
Setup has completed successfully. SQL Server is now starting.
```

The last line is wrong, SQL Server does not start.

I assume that uninstallation leaves some trace of my old evaluation that is detected when I try to set up the new developer installation. Anyone knows if there is a way to get rid of whatever is blocking the new install?

TIA,
Gunnar

Comment: I ended up running into the same. Apparently there is a new apt repository as an apt-get update didn't show any updates, but after following the instructions for the CU repository installation, it ended up upgrading mssql-server. That solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks, that was it!

Answer (score 0):

Shane's comment answered the question. Replacing the repository according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-suse did the trick!